# Date Picker in Titanium Appcelerator iOS app doesn't show a submit button in simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, appcelerator

I'm repurposing an iOS app I built using Appcelerator that was originally built for Android. Most of the code base works except for specific Android code I used for specific features. One feature is allowing the user of the iOS app to select a date once a button is pressed.

At the moment I have this code:

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    value:minDate
});

pickBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    winscrollView.add(picker);
});
```

This works - to a point. When the button is pressed the date picker is displayed. However, no submit, cancel buttons are present on the screen at the same time. Here is a screen shot of the app running in the simulator:

[image]

I've clicked every part of the screen to no avail. The date picker is responsive, and I can select a date. But I've no way to them submit this to the app. I'm not sure what can be causing this bug, as I've no iPhone to hand right now to try the app out on the phone.

I'm using the Titanium SDK 3.3.0 GA and Xcode 5 because I'm using Mountain Lion (10.8.4).

Answer (score 1):

first create view and then add date picker and button into this view .
like that,

```
var pickerView = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundcolor : 'white', height : Ti.UI.SIZE,}); 

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
minDate: minDate,
maxDate: maxDate,
value:minDate });


var submitBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({title :'submit',height : 50,width:100,backGroundColor : 'black',color:'white' });

pickerView.add(submitBtn);

  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
winscrollView.remove(pickerView); });

pickBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
winscrollView.add(pickerView); });
```